# django url field more than once without using many key

Tags: python, django

I want to have more than one url field. 
How do I submit more than one in the admin.
is there an option i can put in for this?

```
class Episode(models.Model):

    link = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Typically you make a model `EpisodeUrl`, with a `link`, and a `ForeignKey` to the `Episode`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I know that but I feel like there will be a better way no?

Comment: @user2998413 what Willem Van Onsem says is the best practice. It is called **database normalization**

Comment: @HuLuViCa I guess I should go with that one then